# Continuity of a functional on space of compactly supported smooth function

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, continuity, distribution-theory, schwartz-space

Assume $n\geq 3$. Let $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be the space of compactly supported real valued smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$ endowed with $L^\infty$ norm. For $f\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$, let $\hat{f}$ donote it's fourier transform. Define the functional $T: C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)\to\mathbb{R}$ by 
$$ T(f) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{|\hat{f}(x)|^2}{||x||^2}\,dx $$

Show that T is well-defined.
Is T continuous?

I was able to show that T is well-defined i.e the integral is finite but could not prove the continuity part. Any help is appreciated!

Update: I am starting to think that T may not be continuous in max norm. So I have changed the question.

Comment: Which bound did you get for the integral to show that it is finite?

Comment: I used the local integrability of $\frac{1}{||x||^2}$ to bound the integral on ball and the polynomial decay of $\hat{f}$ outside the ball to bound the other part of the integral.

Comment: Because $f \mapsto |\hat{f}|^2$ is continuous $C^\infty_c \to L^1 \cap L^\infty$  and $\frac{1}{\|x\|^2} \in L^1(\|x\| < 1) , L^\infty(\|x\| \ge 1)$ then yes $f \mapsto T(f)$ is continuous for the $C^\infty_c$ topology.

Answer (score 0):

More generally, consider the bilinear form
$$
C(f,g)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{\overline{\widehat{f}(x)}\widehat{g}(x)}{||x||^2}\ dx\ .
$$
It is easy to show it is continuous since it satisfies a bound
$$
|C(f,g)|\le \rho(f)\rho(g)
$$
for some continuous seminorm $\rho$.
Then compose with the diagonal map $f\mapsto(f,f)$ to get that $T(f)=C(f,f)$
is continuous.